# Processing CSV file using C#

Tags: c#, csv

I am creating a CSV Importing tool (comma separated). I am trying to make this importing tool as generic as possible , so that it can process any CSV File.

I have almost finalised the tool , but came across one file which I am finding it difficult to process.

How can I process the file with data in following format?

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5
----------
alex,p,22323,23232,hello
mike,t,"121212,232323,4343434",33432,hi
guna,s,"2423,2332",whats
cena,a,34443,33432,up
```

Since the file is comma separated, and one of its value is comma separated as well between identifier `"value,value,value"`  I am finding it difficult to process.

How can i tackle this issue?

I donot have control over CSV file. So I cant change the format

Comment: Use a [CSV parser](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+csv+parser).

Comment: A naive approach would be to read in each line, split on ',' and if the resulting array doesn't have the correct number of elements (i.e. same number of elements as the column declarations), ignore it. Alternatively, you could special case '-' separators

Comment: Thanks guys ! will look in to CSV Parser as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @dtb... [use a CSV parser](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc#%5D%20csv%20parser). If you reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic` then you can:

```
var data=@"column1,column2,column3,column4,column5
----------
alex,p,22323,23232,hello
mike,t,""121212,232323,4343434"",33432,hi
guna,s,""2423,2332"",whats
cena,a,34443,33432,up";

using (var sr = new StringReader(data))
using (var parser =
    new TextFieldParser(sr)
        {
            TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited,
            Delimiters = new[] { "," },
            CommentTokens = new[] { "--" }
        })
{
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fields;
        fields = parser.ReadFields();
        //yummy
    }
}
```

This deals with quotes correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the solution . So with the commenttoken how to use doubleinverted comma ?

Comment: @wcraft: Why do you want to use doubleinverted comma as a comment? You do understand that the CSV "spec" allows for doubleinverted comma so that you can quote stuff with delimiters, right? This means that the field will contain something like `2423,2332` (comma included).